# $emit not working while emit data from one controller to another controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I try to call function while emit data from one controller to another
in AngularJS. But it doesn't work for me in Angular v.1.2. I need to call `ctrl1` function from `ctrl2`. Anyone can give me some idea for this issue?

**Sample code:**

```
    <div ng-contorller="ctrl">
      <div ng-contorller="ctrl1">
      </div>
      <div ng-contorller="ctrl2">
      </div>
    </div>

function parentctrl(){

}
function ctrl1($scope){
 $scope.callfn = function(){
 console.log("success");
}
 $scope.$on('emitdata', function(event, data){
    $scope.callfn();
 })
}
function ctrl2($scope){       
 $scope.$emit('emitdata', {'key':'uu'});
}
```

Comment: You should post your markup as well. The order in which the controllers are declared matters. There's nothing obviously wrong with your code.

Comment: ok, i will check with this

Comment: It all depends on how your controllers are nested. Try $rootScope.$emit(), does it work then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you could use both emits and broadcasts. Child scopes emits, parents broadcast. Like so: http://plnkr.co/edit/pjGIHByzkwCeNiaVrdb6?p=preview

```
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('emitdata', function(event, data) {
    // This event will reach: ctrl -> ctrl1 + ctrl2
    $scope.$broadcast('broadcast-data', data);
  });
});

app.controller("ctrl1", function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('broadcast-data', function(event, data) {
    $scope.received = data;
  })
});

app.controller("ctrl2", function($scope) {
  $scope.emit = function() {
    // This event will reach: ctrl2 -> ctrl -> rootScope
    $scope.$emit('emitdata', {'key': 'uu'}); 
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$emit` propagates events upwards, meaning that the emitting controller should be inside the listening controller.

```
<div ng-controller="ctrlone">
    <div ng-controller="ctrltwo">
        <!-- ctrltwo is the emitting controller
             ctrlone is the listening controller -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Now if there are two controllers that are on the same level like this:

```
<div ng-controller="parent">
    <div ng-controller="ctrlone">
        <!-- i listen for an event -->
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="ctrltwo">
        <!-- i raise an event -->
    </div>
</div>
```

There is no direct way for `ctrlone` to communicate with `ctrltwo` and vice versa. What you can do in this situation is to use `$rootScope.$broadcast` instead of `emit`:

```
function ctrltwo($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('myEvent', {'key':'uu'});
}

function ctrlone($scope) {
    $scope.$on('myEvent', function(event, data){
        $scope.callfn();
    });
}
```

You can also use `$scope.$parent` instead of `$rootScope`, but be careful when doing this, because this may stop working if the controller nesting changes.

Comment: i have try this emit data from one controller to another controller inside parent controller..ctrl1 and ctrl2 placed inside one parent controller. what will i do for this

Answer (score 0):

This is how ctrl2 function should look:

```
function ctrl2($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('emitdata', {'key':'uu'});
}
```

$emit is to send up, $broadcast is to send down. $rootScope is at the top.